# NVelocity ASP.NET Examples

Tags: asp.net, nvelocity

I'm looking to use NVelocity in my ASP.NET MVC application, not as a view engine, just for rendering some email templates.

However, I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I have downloaded it from the castle project and followed the example at http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/usingit.html#step1

No matter what I try I don't seem to be able to load a template located in my site. The example suggests using the absolute path, which I have tried to no avail:

```
Template t = engine.GetTemplate("/Templates/TestEmail.vm");
```

So please can someone give me two examples. One of loading a template located in the web site directory and secondly one parsing a string variable (as it is likely that my templates will be stored in a database).

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: not sure if this will help but theres a pretty good article here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/nvelocityaspnet.aspx

Comment: @rohancragg - yes I saw this article. It is quite old though and the methods used to process the templates seem to have changed since the project was taken over by Castle. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used this class in one of my past projects:

```
public interface ITemplateRepository
{
    string RenderTemplate(string templateName, IDictionary<string, object> data);
    string RenderTemplate(string masterPage, string templateName, IDictionary<string, object> data);
}

public class NVelocityTemplateRepository : ITemplateRepository
{
    private readonly string _templatesPath;

    public NVelocityTemplateRepository(string templatesPath)
    {
        _templatesPath = templatesPath;
    }

    public string RenderTemplate(string templateName, IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        return RenderTemplate(null, templateName, data);
    }

    public string RenderTemplate(string masterPage, string templateName, IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The \"templateName\" parameter must be specified", "templateName");
        }

        var name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPage)
            ? masterPage : templateName;

        var engine = new VelocityEngine();
        var props = new ExtendedProperties();
        props.AddProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, _templatesPath);
        engine.Init(props);
        var template = engine.GetTemplate(name);
        template.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8.BodyName;
        var context = new VelocityContext();

        var templateData = data ?? new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var key in templateData.Keys)
        {
            context.Put(key, templateData[key]);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPage))
        {
            context.Put("childContent", templateName);
        }

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            engine.MergeTemplate(name, context, writer);
            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to instantiate the `NVelocityTemplateRepository` class you need to provide an absolute path where your templates root is. Then you use relative paths to reference your `vm` files.

Comment: @Darin, I tried your example but still get the same error when trying to load the template file. Perhaps I am passing my paths in incorrectly. The template in question is ~/Content/Templates/TestEmail.vm and my code is below: 

var templatesPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/templates"); ITemplateService templateService = new NVelocityTemplateService(templatesPath); var objs = new Dictionary<string, object>(); return templateService.RenderTemplate("TestEmail.vm", objs);

Comment: VirtualPathUtility does not return absolute path. You need to pass an absolute path such as `c:\mytemplates`. Try this instead: `Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, @"Content\templates")`.

Comment: I changed to Server.MapPath to get physical directory on server. Now works a treat. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also added the following method to process a string instead of a template file (say if retrieving the template content from a database):

```
        public string RenderTemplateContent(string templateContent, IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateContent))
            throw new ArgumentException("Template content cannot be null", "templateContent");

        var engine = new VelocityEngine();
        engine.Init();

        var context = GetContext(data);

        using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
            engine.Evaluate(context, writer, "", templateContent);
            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

And used StructureMap to initialize the service:

```
            ForRequestedType<ITemplateService>()
            .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(()=> 
                new NVelocityTemplateService(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Templates/")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [TemplateEngine component](http://www.castleproject.org/components/templateengine/index.html) useful.

It's an abstraction over template engines with a NVelocity implementation, similar to [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461704/nvelocity-asp-net-examples/2461723#2461723), but it should perform marginally better since it uses a single instance of the VelocityEngine (as opposed to initializing one instance per render) and has optional caching. It also has a couple other features, like logging, NVelocity property overriding and loading templates from assembly resources.