# Any template engine similar to freetemplate for C#?

Tags: c#, templates

I'm looking for a template engine like freemarker (with select case directive) for writing a generator in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with freemarker, but I believe [NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/index.html) may do what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks Dathan, ive seen nvelocity, but it seems it has no select directive (although there is a implementacion in castle nvelocity port), i need the select directive to do this:
select case field.type
case int:
bla , bla

Comment: In most cases, `switch` or `select case` structures are just a shorthand way of representing an if/then/else control structure.  (Exceptions are languages where `case` blocks are expressions, and if/then/else are statements).  NVelocity does not have a `case` structure, but does have an [if/then/else control structure](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Conditionals).

Comment: youre right dathan, but i think its a more elegant way to do, its like using spaguetti programming or not...
i was wrong with castle nvelocity, they dont use select case either, http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/improvements.html

Comment: If it doesn't do what you want, you shouldn't accept my answer unless it turns out there isn't a better option for what you want to do.  That having been said, if you're willing to consider commercial offerings, there's [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/) is a template engine I've used to generate emails. Here's how your code [might look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461704/nvelocity-asp-net-examples/2461723#2461723).